# how to compare strings in python with "\r" and "\n"

Tags: python, string

I have 2 strings

```
str1 = "SWITCH ASSY  Drawing No.: NA  "
str2 = "SWITCH ASSY\r\nDrawing No.: NA\r\n"
```

Python evaluates `str1 == str2` as `False` and it is pretty obvious why.

What can I do to **str1** so that the "\r" and "\n" are ignored and `str1 == str2` becomes `True`?

Suppose I can only manipulate str1. Is it even possible?

Comment: What can you do to *`str2`* to make it equal `str1`…?!

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question. Ideally, I only want to manipulate str1 but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Well, you could replace double-spaces with `\r\n`… but is that really a safe thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a regex replacement on all whitespace characters, and replace them with single spaces:

```py
str1 = "SWITCH ASSY  Drawing No.: NA  "
str2 = "SWITCH ASSY\r\nDrawing No.: NA\r\n"

if re.sub(r'\s', ' ', str1) == re.sub(r'\s', ' ', str2):
    print("EQUAL")  # prints EQUAL
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this…?

Comment: @deceze I didn't see that the OP's strings had CRLF in the middle of the string.  I misread and thought it was only at the end, for which my original answer would have been valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use replace('\r',' ') and replace('\n',' ') before u compare them

Comment: That'll produce `"...ASSYDrawing..."`, which doesn't equal `"...ASSY  Drawing..."`…

Comment: Ok you are right does need to be spaces, I will change that

Answer (score 0):

Simple replace two spaces with `\r\n`

```
str1 = str1.replace("  ","\r\n")
```

Test code

```
str1 = "SWITCH ASSY  Drawing No.: NA  "
str2 = "SWITCH ASSY\r\nDrawing No.: NA\r\n"
str1 = str1.replace("  ", "\r\n")
print(str2 == str1)
# Output
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this before you compare them:

```
str2 = str2.replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ")
```